# PHP - Replace values of array with another non identical array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way i can replace the values of one array with the values of another non identical array and obtain as result only the first (updated) array? 
For example:

```
$arr1 = Array
        (
            [key3] => var3
            [key4] => var4
        )
$arr2 = Array
        (
            [key1] => var1
            [key2] => var2
            [key3] => new_var
            [key4] => new_var
            [key5] => var5
            [key6] => var6
        )
```

I want to get:

```
$arr_result = Array
        (
            [key3] => new_var
            [key4] => new_var
        )

$arr_result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2)
```

is not the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you can use [`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) along with [`array_keys_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_replace($arr1, $arr2), $arr1);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d4d40a394183b51bec95342c869d82adeaa5478).

However simply looping through the first array and replacing values yourself is more optimal in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the first array to replace the value of the second array if they have the same key. You can use foreach or array_walk()

```
foreach($array1 as $k => &$v)
{
  $v = isset($array2[$k]) ? $array2[$k] : $v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

> Returns an associative array containing all the entries of `first argument` which have keys that are present in all arguments.

---

```
$arr_result = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: It's a good solution but it's not exactly what i want to get. The result i want is always all the keys of the first array (with updated values)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $arr2))
        $arr1[$key] = $arr2[$key];
}
```

I like this method because the code is concise, efficient, and the functionality reads well straight from the built-in PHP functions used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jomoos anwer i've tried this and it work fine:

```
$arr_res = array_intersect_key($array2, $array1);
return array_merge($array1, $arr_res);
```